# SQL COUNT Return Wrong Number

Tags: mysql, sql-server

so I have a problem with my query. I have 2 tables:

courses:

The `user_id` in this table is the instructor of the course.

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
| course_id   |    user_id    |   course_name     | other information |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
| 6           |       1       |   My Course 1     | ...               |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

my_courses:

The `user_id` in this table is a student of the course.

```
--------------------------------------------------
| user_id     | course_id  | created_at          |
--------------------------------------------------
| 5           | 6          | [UNIX_TIMESTAMP]    |
--------------------------------------------------
```

The `my_courses` contains the number of people that have joined that course. I want to get all the course info as well as the number of people that have joined a course. Everything returns as expected except the number of people that joined a course. This is the query I'm using:

```
        SELECT 
            courses.*,
            users.name, //This is the name of the instructor
            users.last_name, //This is the last name of the instructor
            COUNT(my_courses.user_id) as count_students

        FROM courses

        LEFT JOIN users
        ON courses.user_id = courses.user_id

        LEFT JOIN my_courses
        ON courses.course_id = my_courses.course_id

        WHERE courses.course_id = '6'
```

Like I said, this query returns the course info like normal but returns `3` as `count_students` when it should only return `1`. Does anyone know why this is happening? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please tag the correct RDBMS. You need a `GROUP BY` clause to get the correct count.

Comment: Maybe it's counting the returned rows, not specifically from the `my_courses` table

Comment: Your sample data doesn't help the question.

Comment: `ON courses.user_id = courses.user_id` ... is this a typo?

Comment: Yeah, I just noticed it right now. Haha, It's working now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably because of the  `JOIN` condition for `users`. It should be:

```
LEFT JOIN users
        ON courses.user_id = users.user_id
```

You should also add a `GROUP BY` clause in your query:

```
SELECT 
    c.*,
    u.name, 
    u.last_name,
    COUNT(mc.user_id) AS count_students
FROM courses c
LEFT JOIN users u
    ON c.user_id = u.user_id
LEFT JOIN my_courses mc
    ON c.course_id = mc.course_id
WHERE c.course_id = '6'
GROUP BY
    <columns not in the aggregate function>
```

Additionally, alias your tables to improve readability.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I just noticed. Let me try that out.

Comment: Turn out it was this typo. And thanks for the suggestion, I'll keep that in mind. Thanks again! :)

Answer (score 1):

JOIN operations cause combinatorial multiplication of rows. You need to summarize the student count from its own table like so.

```
                      SELECT course_id, COUNT(*) students
                        FROM my_courses
                    GROUP BY course_id
```

That gives you a result set with either one or zero rows per course_id. You can then join it to the rest of your query.

```
SELECT courses.*,
       users.name, //This is the name of the instructor
       users.last_name, //This is the last name of the instructor
       aggr.count_students
  FROM courses
  LEFT JOIN users  ON courses.user_id = courses.user_id
  LEFT JOIN (
                 SELECT course_id, COUNT(*) students
                   FROM my_courses
                GROUP BY course_id
       ) aggr ON courses.course_id = aggr.course_id
 WHERE courses.course_id = '6'
```

That way you'll avoid multiple-counting your students for courses with, perhaps, more than one instructor.